# map вставка с условием

Tags: c++, map

массив

```
 float v[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0}
```

Нужно проверять в map, существует ли в ключе значение из
 массива v, если да, то присваивать его значению тотже инкремент.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 9; i ++) 
 map.insert(std::pair<float,int>(v[i],i));

 0.5 : 0 
 0.5 : 0 
 0.0 : 1 
 0.5 : 0 
 1.0 : 2 
 0.0 : 1 
 0.5 : 0 
-0.5 : 3 
 0.0 : 1
```

Вопрос: можно ли делать проверку существования ключа в map на этапе вставки?

Comment: Постановка задачи бессмысленна. Нет никакого смысла вставлять в map пары, у которых совпадает и ключ, и данные. Очевидно, имеет место XY-проблема, т.е. вам на самом деле ничего этого не нужно. Опишите более общую задачу - к чему это все и что вы этим пытаетесь решить.

Answer (score 1):

"Тот же инкремент" — это как расшифровывается? Подсчитать, сколько раз в массиве встречается каждое значение? Если массив небольшой, можно использовать `map::operator[]`, он вставляет value-initialized элемент, если ключа еще нет в мапе:

```
std::map<float, ::std::size_t> histogram;
for(::std::size_t i{}; i < sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]); ++i) {
    ++histogram[v[i]];
}
```

Comment: > "Тот же инкремент" — это как расшифровывается? Подсчитать, сколько раз в массиве встречается каждое значение?

у первого элемента 0.5 будет значение инкремента 0, второй элемен 0.5 - тоже значение 0, третий 1.0 - 1, четвёртый опять 0.5 - значение 0.

Comment: Инкремент чего?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, стоит лишь проверить значение, возвращаемое `insert`:

```
auto const insertion_result{map.emplace(v[i], i)};
if(insertion_result.second)
{
     // элемент добавлен
}
else
{  
     // элемент уже был
}
```

А `insertion_result.first` будет итератором на элемент.

Comment: нет, так не получается. map, только уникальный вставляет.
Т.е. нужно чтобы у однотипных ключей были одинаковые значения, как описал в первом посте.

Comment: @Slaine: Постановка задачи бессмысленна. Нет никакого смысла вставлять в map пары, у которых совпадает и ключ, и данные. Очевидно, имеет место XY-проблема. Вам на самом деле ничего этого не нужно.

Comment: Да, не правильно составил вопрос.
v[] = {0.5, 0,5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0} 

нужно проиндесировать каждую группу из трёх чисел массива целыми числами начиная с нуля и записать индексы в другой массив, т.е. для первых трёх чисел будет всегда 0.
например: 0.0, 5.0, 0.5, 1.0 - индекс ноль, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс ноль(т.к. числа уже встречались), -0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 2,
1.0, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 - индекс 3 и т.д.

новый массив должен получится таким: 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3

Comment: @Slaine Ну тогда надо было добавить это все в вопрос (а лучше создать новый.

Answer (score 0):

```
float v[] = {0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.0, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0};
std::map<float, size_t> m{{-0.5, 3}, {1.0, 2}, {0.0, 0}}, handler(m);
for (auto &p : handler) //эта таблица с ключами  из m
    p.second = 1;       // со значениями 1
for(int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    float f(v[i]);
    if (handler[f] != 1) continue; // если ключа нет, то ничего не делаем
    m[f] = i;        
    std::cout  << v[i] << '\t' << m[f] <<'\n';
}
```

Вы наверное так хотели?

Comment: Спасибо. Похоже, но не то. Вот исправил вопрос:
массив {0.5, 0,5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0} 
нужно проиндесировать каждую группу из трёх чисел массива целыми числами начиная с нуля и записать индексы в другой массив, т.е. для первых трёх чисел будет всегда 0.
например: 0.0, 5.0, 0.5, 1.0 - индекс ноль, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс ноль(т.к. числа уже встречались), -0.5, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 2,
1.0, 0.5, 0.0 - индекс 1, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 - индекс 3 и т.д.
новый массив должен получится : 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 3, 3